# Extracting a specific list item using Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the "Balance" integer value from [this webpage](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/address/3CpfD1gBBdNW7orErj3YyNNSVpzndZ9aP9/) but am having trouble figuring out how to isolate that list item.

This is the code I currently have:

```
import bs4, requests

res = requests.get('https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/address/3CpfD1gBBdNW7orErj3YyNNSVpzndZ9aP9/')
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
elems = [elem for elem in soup.findAll('li') if 'Balance' in str(elem.text)]

print(elems)
```

However when I run it all I get is a [] instead of the real balance value.

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number, you can use this:

```
balance = soup.find('span', text='Balance').parent.contents[3].strip()
print(balance)
```

Output:

```
9.06451275 BTC
```

Explanation:

`soup.find('span', text='Balance')` will get you this `<span class="dash-label">Balance</span>` tag.

Using `.parent.contents` will give the contents of its parent tag as a list. In that list, the text you want is located in the 3rd index.

```
>>> for i, content in enumerate(soup.find('span', text='Balance').parent.contents):
...     print(i, content)
...
0

1 <span class="dash-label">Balance</span>
2 <br/>
3
            9.06451275 BTC


4 <br/>
5

6 <span class="dash-label">
                (-0.0500349 BTC unconfirmed)
              </span>
7
```

Comment: Perfect, but how exactly do you figure out that it is in the 3rd index?

Comment: Just print the list once and check the index of the required part. Check the edit. I've added that part.

Comment: Any reason why I get error messages instead of values if I try using index values 1,2,4,5 or 6? Just asking since I am trying to learn and don't understand why it would not at least return something.

Comment: Remove the `.strip()` part and you wont get any errors. `.strip()` works only on a string and not on tags. Actually it works on 0,3,5,7 (they are all strings) but not on others.